# How to add a new flutter project as a IntelliJ module in a larger project

Tags: flutter, gradle, intellij-idea, plugins, module

I have a single INTELLIJ project, with 4 java modules and 4 python modules, each is also pretty much a separate sub-project in gradle. Now, in an i**solated module in the same project** I want a flutter app.

Eventually I might want to make custom gradle tasks to run flutter as a subproject so that I can build all from gradle but that is way down the road. Right now I'm trying to **get the intelliJ flutter plugin to work with the flutter project as a module** (instead of the base folder, one level down, app/flutterApp/[Anything Flutter Needs]).

The dream is to have these 9 projects in the same folder, master project, git and build pipeline as a single set without losing functionality... if it can happen **without touching android studio** even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instructions (So far):

- File - new - module, then select flutter.
- Add the module in project structure so it's inline with the others (use dot notation to signify module groups/folders).
- Add "Dart SDK", "Dart Packages" and "Flutter Plugins" Dependencies in the said tab of the module.
- Set the flutter sdk location (File - Settings - Languages - Flutter)
- **RUN main.dart**: This allows the flutter plugin to recognize it; sadly after figuring the rest out, this is what thwarted the effort.